# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to do a project with primefaces. When I run the wildfly server, it gives me this error.

```
13:19:44,156 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TECIntranet.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TECIntranet.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "TECIntranet.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/chart/ChartSeries
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries from [Module "deployment.TECIntranet.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 14 more
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Your title was very bad. See the improvement BalusC did? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61867770/revisions And also check his comment.Version info should be in the content of the question unless it e.g. works in WildFly 14 and not in 16. And now you know the ClassNotfoundException is your core problem, please investigate that by using a searchengine (and use that it is thrown from hte ModuleClassLoader... etc..

Comment: Primefaces version? Have you checked your war to see if primefaces jar is there?